# Why not isomorphic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism

Need to show why $(S_7,\circ)$ is not isomorphic to $(\Bbb Z/100\Bbb Z,+)$.  I think it might have something to do with Abelian, but I'm not sure.

Comment: $S_7$ has $7! = 5040$ elements, while $Z/100Z$ has $100$ elements, so the two groups don't have the same cardinality, so there cannot be a bijection between the two. Correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't that enough to show that the two are not isomorphic?

Comment: But it's true that ${\mathbb Z}/100{\mathbb Z}$ is abelien and $S_7$ is not, so that provides an alternative proof!

Comment: @dan I would begin by carefully reading the definition of "isomorphic" or "isomorphism".

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, the simplest way to show that $S_7$ is not isomorphic to $\Bbb{Z}/100\Bbb{Z}$ is to consider their cardinalities.

$S_7$ has $7! = 5040$ elements, and $\Bbb{Z}/100\Bbb{Z}$ has $100$ elements. Since the two groups have different cardinalities, there cannot exist a bijection between the two. An isomorphism is necessarily a bijection, so there cannot exist an isomorphism between $S_7$ and $\Bbb{Z}/100\Bbb{Z}$. Hence, the two are not isomorphic.

Comment: as simple as that\